# Load data in one div and clear the other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load content in one div and clear the other div.

So I have this body tag and inside it :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="divs">
                <canvas id="div1"></canvas>
                <canvas id="div2"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type='text' placeholder="Type here..." name='fname' class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
            <input class="shadow mx-3" type="button" value="Play 1" id="clickMe" onclick="animation('div1')" />
            <input class="shadow mx-3" type="button" value="Play 2" id="clickMe1" onclick="animation('div2')" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then when user click on button Play1, the content inside div1 should load and when clicked on div2 the content inside div1 should be clear and load inside div2. Well the content is loading fine but when click on Play1 it loads in div1 and then when I click on Play2 it loads in div2 without clearing the content of div1. I don't seem to find any solution for this.

```
function animation(divi) {
            var scene = new davePlugin(divi, input);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Explanation:
I am trying to load 3d space inside canvas tag on button click, so when I click on Play1 the 3d space will load in canvas with id="div1' and when I click on Play2 the 3d space will load in canvas with id="div2". I want to clear all content of canvas and then load the content in specific canvas id to which button corresponds to.

Comment: Could you please add the JavaScript that goes with the HTML? Neither elements are `<div>` elements. Do you mean clearing the first canvas?

Comment: What data format do you want to load into divs?

Comment: Data format is 3d space using babylon

Answer (score 1):

I do not clearly understand your request, but I think this is your answer

```
<script>
 function animation (element) {
    if(elemet === "div1") {
      document.querySelector("#div2").innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector("div1").innterHTML = "Hi";
    }
    else if(element === "div2"){
      document.querySelector("#div1").innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector("div2").innterHTML = "Hi";
    }
    else { return false }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey can you give me a more dynamic solution in which if there is more than one div and I have to clear all of them and load content only in one specific div.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

1. If you are only displaying text :

```
document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
```

2. if you have child nodes created under div1:

```
function clear() {
 var div = document.getElementById(elementID); 
              
 while(div.firstChild) { 
 div.removeChild(div.firstChild); 
 } 
}
```